# How to find the index of an element in an numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array `df` in which each element is a list of 2 numbers. Given an element `p = [18, 169]`. I would like to find the indices of such elements `p` in `df`. Given `df`

```
[[[13, 169],    [18, 169],  [183, 169]],
 [[-183, 169],  [18, 169],  [183, 169]],
 [[18, 169],    [-18, 169], [183, 169]]]
```

With `(df == p).all(-1)`, I get

```
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

What I want is

```
[[0, 1],
 [1, 1],
 [2, 0]]
```

Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

```
import numpy as np
df = np.array([[[13, 169],   [18, 169], [183, 169]],
               [[-183, 169], [18, 169], [183, 169]],
               [[18, 169],   [-18, 169], [183, 169]]])
p = [18, 169]
ind = (df == p).all(-1)
ind
```

Comment: `df` is not a 2D array, but a 3D array.  You can check this via: `df.ndim`, which returns `3`.

Comment: Thank you @James, fixed.

Comment: @James I posted an answer with `np.stack(np.where((df == p).all(-1)))`. It produces what I'm looking for. I wonder why you deleted it.

Comment: I deleted my answer because @Hans Musgrave had a better answer using a shorter version of the numpy API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've computed with `(df==p).all(-1)` is a *mask*. They have lots of uses, but you can use that directly to compute the value you want.

```
# True or false at each coordinate
mask = (df==p).all(-1)

# Extract the coordinates where the mask is True
result = np.argwhere(mask)
```

Comment: So elegant. Thank you so much!!